# Laptop auto-loads my browser on startup?

Tags: windows, boot, google-chrome

When I turn my laptop on, it seems to automatically load Google Chrome and open the most recent pages I was on. Today it loaded up YouTube and even automatically started playing the video

Also when I open Chrome in general, it does the same thing (opening all previous pages without me doing so). I have checked Task Manager and disabled Google Chrome from startup, although this doesn't fix the issue. Also in Chrome settings, on startup it is set to open Google

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Are you closing chrome before you shutdown/restart? This is typical default behavior of Windows 10.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1146972/how-to-stop-previously-closed-tabs-from-opening-upon-chrome-re-open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Appleoddity, modern Windows 10 includes the feature of re-opening applications that were open when the user was logged out.  In Windows 10v1803 , open Settings->Account->Options and disable "Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device and reopen my apps after an update or restart."